# Is this question related to computer science?

Tags: discussion, scope

> **Efficient directory tree-like data structure for virtual file system?**
>
> I've already ben able to compress and encrypt each individual file
>   using LZ4 and AES but I need to store the tree information so I was
>   thinking maybe to have a hash table of descriptors, where each entry
>   would have the following information:
>
> - Name
> - Position (in the binary container)
> - Size (to be able read only the bytes for that particular file)
> - Type (whether it's a directory or a file)
> - Parent
> - Next sibling
>
> Also, if each hash is computed from the full path in the original
>   directory, extracting a single file would require only a binary
>   search. But for traversing a directory or extracting multiple files,
>   the fields for **parent** and **next sibling** in the descriptor could be used
>   instead, so no more binary searches are needed after the first
>   descriptor is returned from the hash table.

Comment: 1) I don't see a question there. 2) It seems that you are well into implementation detail territory. That's probably less suited for [cs.SE] than [SO] or maybe one of the more specialized sites.